# openssl RAND_add() documentation refers to RFC1750. RFC1750 is silent on the matter

Tags: c++, c, random, openssl, cryptography

The documentation for the openssl library's `RAND_add` function has this to say about the entropy argument:

> The entropy argument is (the lower bound of) an estimate of how much randomness is contained in buf, measured in bytes. Details about sources of randomness and how to estimate their entropy can be found in the literature, e.g. RFC 1750.

source: http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand_add

RFC 1750 can be found here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1750.html

... but of course it is completely silent on the subject of "entropy" (a text search reveals zero occurrences of this word in the document).

So here are my questions:

1. What specifically is the entropy argument supposed to be a measurement of?
2. What is the valid range of values (the argument is of type double)?

Many thanks.

Comment: It does somewhat go into the territory of entropy in [section 4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1750.html#section-4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What specifically is the entropy argument supposed to be a measurement of?

How unpredictable the input is to an attacker.

> What is the valid range of values (the argument is of type double)

The value should be the natural log of the number of guesses you expect an attacker would need to guess the contents of the input divided by 8. This is basically the same as the number of bytes of entropy the input contains.

Comment: so in effect, if my buffer is believed to be truly random, `entropy` should be equal to `double(num)`?

Comment: @RichardHodges Correct. If you believe it is perfectly unpredictable and incompressible, then the amount of entropy is equal to the size.

Comment: so the reason for this entropy argument's presence is for example when I'm collecting 32-bit data from some random source (such as a mouse) but only the first (say) 10 bits are likely to change? In which case my entropy would be log(1024)/8 ~= 0.87 whereas the bufsize would be 4?

Comment: @RichardHodges Right. This allows you to use an entropy source that's less than perfect without misleading the entropy pool.

Comment: Thank you. What a shame that this extremely important and fundamental information is not in the OpenSSL documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It may not use the word, but the entire RFC is about entropy. It uses the word ['unpredictability'](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1750.html#section-4) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Per the "man" page you cited:

> http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand_add
>
> RAND_seed() is equivalent to RAND_add() when num == entropy.

Here is a discussion about the "entropy" argument:

> https://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-dev@openssl.org/msg09806.html
>
> > Lutz Jaenicke wrote:
> >
> > > The entropy parameter should tell, how much "uncertainty" is in the
> > > data provided.
> >
> > > If we choose a value of 0, we mean that there may be entropy in it, but
> > > maybe an attacker can predict the value, so we use it but do not count
> > > it as a really unpredictable input.
> >
> > So, if we know the entropy per character (byte) what's the correct
> > formula for deriving the correct value for the entropy parameter?
>
> If the entropy is 10% (compress ration 1:10), the parameter is "number
> of bytes * 10%".
>
> Please note again, that the compression ration is just the condensed
> amount of information in the message. If we don't know the message, it
> is more or less equivalent to the entropy (unpredictability) in it. If
> the message is known, the entropy (from the cryptographic point of
> view) is zero! It is therefore a difficult decision to finally
> estimate the entropy coming from the source with the compressed size
> being kind of an upper bound.

In other words, if your buffer is "perfectly random", then entropy == bufsize.

Finally, the RFC cited in the rand_add() man page, RFC 1750, has been superseded by RFC 4086:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4086

Comment: re the equivalence of rand_seed and rand_add, I can see that there is an inference to be drawn, but it is vague since it mentions only one data point. The narrative by Lutz seems to me (perhaps because I am not a mathematician) to contain no concrete information at all.